# How to use File library io Java

Tags: java, excel, algorithm, file

How can I save a file from a directory location where I am also reading another file? What I mean is, I am reading a file at a certain directory i.e.

`/Users/haddad/dir1/file.xls`

I have a method which reads file.xls and I make a copy of it (I just copy the file and do an append to the name).

```
public void postProcessing(String fileName) throws Exception {

   // where fileName parameter is the absolute path to the original file.xls

   Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(fileName));
   WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(fileName.replace(".xls", 
                                                         "_generated.xls")), w);

   some more processing...
}
```

My question is, how can I save this file at a different location because my current way it saves the file_generated.xls in the same path where it read the original file.

I'd like to have it saved here:

`/Users/haddad/Desktop/file_generated.xls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons FileUtils class to copy file from one location to another:

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir);
```

This is a generic method for copying any type of file from one location to another. Both srcFile and destFile are instances of File class.